# limiting gesture on view

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

This is how I add gesture on view

```
- (void)_addPanGestureToView:(UIView *)view {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_handlePan:)];
    panGesture.delegate = self;
    panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:panGesture]; 
}
```

Everything is working perfectly, but gesture is on the whole view how could I do something like gesture respond only in half of view?

Comment: Create a UIView you want to add gesture and add the gesture in this View..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use `CGRectContainsPoint()` and check if the touches location within your view is within the area you want it to be. If it isn't, ignore it:

```
- (void)panGestureDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
    CGRect someRect = ...

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(someRect, location)) {
            // point is in specified area
    }
}
```

Comment: if i add scroll view at place where i have disable gesture then scroll will work?

Comment: ok sir thats done and working

Answer (score 4):

Easiest solution would be adding a transparent view on the area where you want you gesture recognizer to work, and add the gesture to that view (and that view as a subview of course).
Somthing like:

```
- (void)_addPanGestureToView:(UIView *)view {
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_handlePan:)];
panGesture.delegate = self;
panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;

UIView *viewForGesture = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(....)]; //your frame
[viewForGesture addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[view addSubview:viewForGesture]; 
}
```