# Move and Scale UIImageView inside UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIImageView` and `UIImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`. This `UIImageView` is a subview of a `UIView`. I want to be able to move and scale this `UIImageView` inside the `UIView`, but have no success so far.

I tried overriding `touchesMoved` to drag the `UIImageView` around but I don't want any part of the image to be seen outside of the `UIView`.

Comment: consider putting your `UIView` inside a `uiscrollview`. This will take care of everything from zooming, to dragging bounds issues.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001668/how-to-drag-certain-image-in-ios/45002245#45002245

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this select clip to bounds its not showing the component outside of view

select uiview -> check mark clip to bound

[image]

Comment: I implemented everything programmatically but clip to bound is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use gestures for your purpose.

Tutorial : 
[link1](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Identifying_Gestures_using_iOS_8_Gesture_Recognizers)
[link2](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-gesture-recognizers/)

As you have mentioned you want to move image inside view, consider limiting the movement.

Some of links for limiting movement :
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403655/limiting-gesture-on-view) 
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048525/how-to-limit-pan-gesture-area)
[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821617/how-to-restrict-a-moveable-view-by-pan-gesture)